# Can jdbc connection be reused after Exception?

Tags: java, jdbc, connection-pooling

If I close a pooled Connection there is a chance of a SQLException.
Do I need to remove the connection object from the pool in this case? Or can I just ignore the Exception and reuse the connection another time?

```
try {
    pooledConnection.close();
} catch(SQLException e) {
    //remove connection from pool?
}
```

Comment: Leave that decision to the *pool*. You client code should not ever have to deal with the decision if and when to remove a connection from the pool. The implementation of the pooled connection (should) already make the proper decision (within the close method).